# Bash script to split file into two files while changing output file during processing

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to split a text file into two different files, file looks something like this:

```
//ABC12//burrito (line of text)
(line of text)
(line of text)
etc
//ABC12//taco (line of text)
(line of text)
(line of text)
etc
//ABC12//taco (line of text)
(line of text)
(line of text)
etc
//ABC12//burrito (line of text)
(line of text)
(line of text)
etc
```

So I would want to split any line beginning with burrito and all subsuquent lines into a file called burrito until a line with taco in it was read, I think the best way to do this would be:

```
for each line in $text;
   if line contains burrito
         outputfile=burrito
         line>>$outputfile
   elseif line contains taco
         outputfile=taco
         line>>$outputfile
   else
         line>>$outputfile
```

but I am not sure, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: fedorqui, thank you for cleaning up my post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with `awk`:

```
awk '/burrito/ {f="burrito"} /taco/ {f="taco"} {print > f}' file
```

#### Explanation

This outputs the lines to a file `f`, the name of which changes when `taco` or `burrito` are found:

- `/burrito/ {f="burrito"}` this means: if the line contains `burrito`, then set the variable `f` to `burrito`.
- `/taco/ {f="taco"}` the same with `taco`.
- {print > f}`prints the line into the file stored in`f`. You can also say`{print > f".txt"}` or something else.

If you want to set a default file name, so that it outputs somewhere else until a `burrito` or `taco` is found, you can say:

```
awk 'BEGIN {f="another_file"} /burrito/ {f="burrito"} /taco/ {f="taco"} {print > f}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `awk` command:

```
wk 'BEGIN{split("burrito taco", a); f=a[1]} {
   for (i=1; i<=length(a); i++) if ($0 ~ a[i]) f=a[i]; print $0 > f}' file
```

- This will redirect all lines containing `taco` to a output file called `taco`
- This will redirect all lines containing `burrito` to a output file called `burrito`
- Instead of `f=a[1]` you can initialize the output file name to something else.

Comment: Yes after reading the question again I think I misunderstood the requirements.